# In Unity, make an object rotate between two angles that are greater than 180 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, robotics

I am trying to simulate a robotic arm in Unity. I am avoiding super expensive addons (500+ euro) that implement these features by default, so I got to somehow manage on my own or with a little bit of help. Currently I am using an addon called Hybrid IK, not that it matters too much, code is just code. So to the problem at hand:

I have a robot with some axes, each one rotating on either X, Y or Z. I am using quaternions to do the rotations, however quaternions have a problem they can only rotate from -180 to 180. The problem is my robot joints rotate more than that. For example my base rotates from -210 to 210. I tried several solutions but nothing worked.

I tried to introduce a method that reads which way the angle moves after passing from point 0 (initial position) and determining the way the angle rotates that way. So a movement going positive for a 210 angle, would mean, limit the angle from 0 to 180 and then once you flip, from -180 to -150. It didn't work.

Then I tried to just force Unity to go the long way, so a limit of 30, would mean that the angle would have to rotate the other way to reach that 30 (from 0 to -180 and then from 180 to 30) hence mimicking a 330 limit angle. That did not work either.

I am kind of stuck and I would really like to figure this out. I will share the code responsible for this function, but since this is a paid asset, I would rather not share too much.

```
        public Quaternion LimitHinge(Quaternion rotation)
        {
            Quaternion offsetRot = Quaternion.Euler(limitsOffset);

            Vector3 offsetSwingAxis = (offsetRot * this.mainAxis);
            Vector3 offsetSecondaryAxis = (offsetRot * this.cross);
            Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref offsetSwingAxis, ref offsetSecondaryAxis);
            Vector3 offsetCrossAxis = Vector3.Cross(offsetSwingAxis, offsetSecondaryAxis);

            Quaternion hingeOffset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(hingeAngleOffset, offsetSwingAxis);
            Quaternion minRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-limitAngle, offsetSwingAxis) * hingeOffset;
            Quaternion maxRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(limitAngle, offsetSwingAxis) * hingeOffset;
            // Calculate the target quaternion for a free 1-degree-of-freedom rotation.
            Quaternion free1DOFTarget = Quaternion.FromToRotation(rotation * offsetSwingAxis, offsetSwingAxis) * rotation;

            // Check if the limit angle is greater than or equal to 180 degrees,
            // if so, no further processing is needed, return the target.
            if (limitAngle >= 180)
                return free1DOFTarget;

            // Calculate the middle limit angle. If the limitAngle is greater than or equal to 90 degrees,
            // the middle limit is 180 degrees minus the limitAngle, otherwise, it's the same as limitAngle.

            // Check if the limitAngle is greater than or equal to 90 degrees.
            float midLimit;
            if (limitAngle >= 90f)
            {
                // If it is, calculate midLimit as 180 degrees minus the limitAngle.
                midLimit = 180 - limitAngle;
            }
            else
            {
                // If not, midLimit is the same as limitAngle.
                midLimit = limitAngle;
            }

            // Calculate the quaternion for the middle limit rotation.
            Quaternion free1DOFMid = Quaternion.RotateTowards(minRotation, maxRotation, midLimit);

            // If the limitAngle is greater than or equal to 90 degrees, apply a 180-degree flip to the middle rotation.
            if (limitAngle >= 90f)
            {
                Quaternion flip180 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, offsetSwingAxis);
                free1DOFMid *= flip180;
            }

            // Store the original target quaternion for comparison.
            Quaternion lastRotation = free1DOFTarget;

            // Calculate the angle between the target and middle limit rotations.
            float angle = Quaternion.Angle(free1DOFTarget, free1DOFMid);

            // Clamp the middle limit rotation towards the target by the specified limitAngle.
            Quaternion clampedFree1DOF = Quaternion.RotateTowards(free1DOFMid, free1DOFTarget, limitAngle);

            // Determine if the rotation has been clamped to the limit.
            isClampedToLimit = angle >= limitAngle;

            // Return the clamped rotation.
            return clampedFree1DOF;
        }
```

P.S. I did try to contact the creator of the addon, but I couldn't reach him in anyway, seems like he is inactive since 2020 or 2021.

Comment: Interpolate the angle instead, and use `Quaternion.AngleAxis` to construct the rotation from the angle. If you interpolate quaternions it will always rotate the "short way".

Comment: I understand that, but won't that defeat the purpose? Going to 210 degrees is basically going the "long way" as I explained is it not? And I do want to go the long way, or achieve the same effect, essentially being able to rotate from -210 to 210 or -330 to 330 etc. I am sorry if I am misunderstanding something here. I have been trying to fix this for a while now. Seemed like a simple fix but I have been working on it for 3 days now.

Comment: You should probably stick to keeping an angle representation of your rotation, since that is trivial to clamp, interpolate etc, and only convert to quaternions or matrices for the actual rendering. That is assuming each joint can rotate around a single axis. If you have a ball-joints you may need something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your angel from 0 to 1 at first and then multiply and add/subtract it in specific way to get your angles.
so for example you have from -180 to 180, then you need to add to your degrees 180, to get value from 0 to 180 * 2. the next step is to divide degrees, divide by 180 *2 then we got value from 0 to 1. after that you can multiply and add values in the sane way to get value in your custom degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it in a bit of a fake way. Since all my angles can do a -180 to 180 rotation and the angles after that is what matters, I basically hold the total amount an angle has moved in a single direction depending on the starting angle and limit the angle in that way. So a limit angle of 30 will stop the movement of the angle after 180+30 has been done in the direction im moving towards. It isn't perfect, but hey it works!